# image is not showing in wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new in making word press theme. I am trying to call a image from a images folder which is in the theme folder of word press but when I refresh the page then all the page is disappear and nothing is showing even not any php error.

[image: this is the qurrey I am applying and the image is not displaying]

i want to show my logo in the wordpress theme which is like in the image

[image: my wordpress theme]

Comment: if you view the html source and look at the path for the image, what does it say? Is the path correct then?

Comment: image path is correct

Comment: If you validate the HTML with a HTML validator, does everything passes green?

Comment: If the image path is correct then does the image open when you open it directly in the browser.

Comment: I think it has to be `get_template_directory_uri()` instead of `get_template_directory_url()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it has to be `get_template_directory_uri()` instead of `get_template_directory_url()` (lowercase i instead of lowercase l).

You also can use `bloginfo`. See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo

In your case:

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/logo.jpg" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>">
```

And of course make sure you're image is in the right location.